# /dev/mapper/vg_la569-lv_root 100%

Tags: whm

I have problem with hosting server cPanel not working also Mysql not working good

> " The filesystem mounted at / on this server is running out of disk space. cPanel operations have been temporarily suspended to prevent something bad from happening. Please ask your system admin to remove any files not in use on that partition.

from WHM server statues see this error : `/dev/mapper/vg_la569-lv_root 100%`

So what can i do to delete not used file ? 
My datacenter don't provide any help

Answer (score -1):

Your host should provide help with this, are you using a reseller or do you have root access to the node?
If you are independent then you should ssh into the node and proceed to remove files, whereas if you are using a reseller then you will need to continue to pester the host to process your case.

Comment: i have root , and host provider don't support and need money 200$ monthly blacklotus.net

Comment: which files should deleted ?